# Piping to/from Ada program to a C++ program

Tags: c++, pipe, ada

I have used pipes in C/C++ before but I'm working on setting up a pipe in some legacy Ada code...however I am still in the "learning" phase with Ada and there's a lot I still don't yet know.

That being said, I've been trying to figure out how pipes in Ada are setup & how to go about using them. I've only found these articles thus far:

1. [A Thick Ada 95 Binding for Unix Child Processes and Pipes](http://www.adahome.com/articles/1998-02/co_childproc.html)
2. [Package: Util.Pipes](http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/ada95/util/doc/util-pipes.html)
3. [Pipes - ada-util](http://code.google.com/p/ada-util/wiki/Pipes).

Don't get me wrong they have a lot of good knowledge in them, but 1 is geared towards Ada95 (I have the ability to compile up to Ada05), 2 just lists the functions, & 3 offers little in the way of explanation.

Does anyone know of a tutorial for Ada pipes? Or better yet, could someone give a quick example of how to implement a simple pipe in Ada?

I realize that this is not the most ideal question to ask, but I'm running out of "Google Combinations"...

Comment: There's a very good chance that the Ada 95 binding will work unchanged in 05 (and in 12, come to that). Normally we'd avoid recommending AdaHome - it's not been updated for a long time - but if it does the job, great!

Comment: Is there actually an interface to c++ or is it a purely Ada question ?

Comment: @NWS I intend to pipe (or whatever turns out to be the solution) to a C++ program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be more interested in Streams -- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Input_Output/Stream_Tutorial

Especially since, if you make a package that binds a stream to a pipe you get free access with Type_Name'Read( stream, object ) & Type_Name'Write( stream, object ).

Answer (score 2):

## Code

Compiled on Windows 10 with GNAT GPL 2015

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO;
with System;
with Interfaces.C;

procedure Main is

   package Pipes is
      type Pipe is private;
      type Get_Result is private;
      function Open_Read (Command : String) return Pipe;
      procedure Close (Stream : Pipe);
      function Get (Stream : Pipe) return Get_Result;
      function End_Of_File (Item : Get_Result) return Boolean;
      function To_Ada (Item : Get_Result) return Character;
   private
      use System;
      use Interfaces.C;
      type Pipe is new Address;
      type Get_Result is new int;
   end;

   package body Pipes is
      function popen (command : char_array; mode : char_array) return Address with Import, Convention => C, External_Name => "popen";
      function pclose (stream : Address) return int with Import, Convention => C, External_Name => "pclose";
      function fgetc (stream : Address) return int with Import, Convention => C, External_Name => "fgetc";
      function Open_Read (Command : String) return Pipe is
         Mode : constant char_array := "r" & nul;
         Result : Address;
      begin
         Result := popen (To_C (Command), Mode);
         if Result = Null_Address then
            raise Program_Error with "popen error";
         end if;
         return Pipe (Result);
      end;
      procedure Close (Stream : Pipe) is
         Result : int;
      begin
         Result := pclose (Address (Stream));
         if Result = -1 then
            raise Program_Error with "pclose error";
         end if;
      end;
      function Get (Stream : Pipe) return Get_Result is
      begin
         return Get_Result (fgetc (Address (Stream)));
      end;
      function End_Of_File (Item : Get_Result) return Boolean is (Item = -1);
      function To_Ada (Item : Get_Result) return Character is (Character'Val (Get_Result'Pos (Item)));
   end;

   procedure Test is
      use Ada.Text_IO;
      use Pipes;
      P : Pipe;
      C : Get_Result;
   begin
      P := Open_Read ("netstat");
      loop
         C := Get (P);
         exit when End_Of_File (C);
         Put (To_Ada (C));
      end loop;
      Close (P);
   end;

begin
   Test;
end;
```

## Output

The output will differ from user to user .

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    192.168.1.140:49698    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.140:49874    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.140:49915    stackoverflow:https    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.140:49916    stackoverflow:https    TIME_WAIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Ada the language has nothing to say on the subject of pipes; they don't form part of the standard library. I suspect the same is true of C++ and the Boost library (not that I'm a user); pipes are an operating system facility.

Your [article 1](http://www.adahome.com/articles/1998-02/co_childproc.html) contains source which compiles and works with Ada 2005 and Ada 2012 as well as (I expect) Ada 95 - at any rate on Unix systems. Won't that do?

Your article 2 - rather, the `Util` package [found by poking around a bit](http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/ada95/util/index.html) - says it works on Windows and Unix.

The software available at your article 3 has the great advantage of being maintained!

As for a tutorial - since pipes aren't in the standard you have to use what the people who wrote the particular library you choose have provided. Articles 1 and 3 both contain demonstration programs (I haven't checked article 2). I suspect that's it!

Comment: I didn't even realize pipes weren't part of the standard. >.< I appreciate the response, but now I'm thinking streams (as suggested by @Shark8) might be a better fit...

Comment: `ada-util` is so close to supporting Ada streams! The author says it doesn't fit well as a basis for his desired stream types, but I would have thought you could put Ada streams on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overengineering a little, but there is [gnat.sockets](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/GNAT.Sockets) if you are allowed to use gnat libraries.

After all a pipe is a simpler version of a socket (or a socket being an expanded version of a pipe), both allow you to transfer data between tasks/processes.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but as seen in an answer from "What's the difference between pipe and socket" (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3518624/1301332), sockets are slower, and I don't need to worry about connecting to another box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Unix pipes in an Ada application, you should consider the POSIX Ada API, as it is a formal standard.  One implementation of this is the "FLORIST" library.

The [Crimeville language server](http://www.jacob-sparre.dk/spelling/) is an example of how you can use pipes to handle communication between an Ada application and a legacy application with a pipe-friendly interface.