# Read input from a pipe in Ada

Tags: file, pipe, ada

I have a piece of code (see below) that reads data from a file given as a command line argument. I would like to add a support for being able to read the input from a pipe. For instance, the current version reads the data as `main <file_name>`, whereas it should also be possible to do something line `cmd1 | main`. Here is the source to read data from file:

```
procedure main is

    File : Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;

begin

   if Ada.Command_Line.Argument_Count /= 1 then

      return;

   else

      Ada.Text_IO.Open (
         File => File,
         Mode => In_File,
         Name => Ada.Command_Line.Argument (1));

      while (not Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File (File)) loop
         -- Read line using Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line
         -- Process the line
      end loop;

      Ada.Text_IO.Close (File);

end main;
```

If I understood correctly, a pipe is just a non-regular file type in Ada. But how do I deal with it?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, but if you want to access the standard i/O pipes `stdin, stdout, stderr`, look at files such as `Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Output` (ditto Stream_IO etc) e.g. http://ada.tips/redirecting-text_io-output-to-a-file.html

Comment: What I am asking is how to make a program support both reading from a file supplied as a command line argument (which is already done) and also read the input from a pipe in case of such a use. 

Do you mean that a pipe is a just a `stdin`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of these seem to really answer your question. A pipe merely makes the standard output of another program be the standard input of your program, so you read a pipe by reading Standard_Input.

The function Current_Input returns a File_Type. It initially returns Standard_Input, but calling Set_Input changes it to return whatever you passed to Set_Input. So a rough outline of how to read from Standard_Input if no file is given, and from the given file if one is, looks like:

```
File : File_Type;

if Argument_Count > 0 then
   Open (File => File, Name => Argument (1), Mode => In_File);
   Set_Input (File => File);
end if;

All_Lines : loop
   exit All_Lines when End_Of_File (Current_Input);

   Process (Line => Get_Line (Current_Input) );
end loop All_Lines;
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to create a file to be able to read data from pipe.

just

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure main is

    begin

      loop
        exit when Ada.Text_IO.End_Of_File;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Echo" &Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);
      end loop;
end main;
```

And after that `type ..\src\main.adb | main.exe` works.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [the ARM...](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-10-1.html)

> The library package Text_IO has the following declaration:

```
...
package Ada.Text_IO is
...
   -- Control of default input and output files

   procedure Set_Input (File : in File_Type);
   procedure Set_Output(File : in File_Type);
   procedure Set_Error (File : in File_Type);

   function Standard_Input  return File_Type;
   function Standard_Output return File_Type;
   function Standard_Error  return File_Type;

   function Current_Input   return File_Type;
   function Current_Output  return File_Type;
   function Current_Error   return File_Type;
```

which allow you to manipulate the default pipes `stdin, stdout, stderr` as files; either as pre-opened files (input and output pipes) or allow you to redirect stdout to your own file, etc.

[This example](http://ada.tips/redirecting-text_io-output-to-a-file.html) shows redirecting one of the standard pipes to a file and restoring it to the system provided file. Alternatively, File I/O subprograms may be called with the File argument set to e.g. `Ada.Text_IO.Standard_Output` and should simply work as expected - outputting to Terminal or to whatever you piped `stdout` to on the commandline.

Similar facilities should be available in `Direct_IO, Sequential_IO, Stream_IO` etc if the data you're reading and writing isn't text.

Timur's answer shows you can read and write directly to these pipes; this answer's approach allows you to treat the standard pipes uniformly with other files, so that you can I/O either via file or pipe with the same code.  For example, if a commandline filename is supplied, use that file, otherwise point your File at `Standard_Output`.

And if you're asking what happens in the command line `cmd1|main|grep "hello"`, yes, the output of cmd1 is on a pipe called `stdout` (in C) or `Standard_Output` (Ada) which is connected via the (Unix-specific pipe command) | to the `Standard_Input` of your `main` program written in Ada. In turn, its `Standard_Output` is piped into grep's `stdin` which it searches for "hello".

If you are asking how you open and access named pipes, I suspect that is OS specific, and may be a more difficult question.

(In which case, [this Stack Exchange Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428961/piping-to-from-ada-program-to-a-c-program) may help).